# Output Dataframe to CSV File using Repartition and Coalesce

Tags: dataframe, csv, hadoop, pyspark, export-to-csv

Currently, I am working on a single node Hadoop and I wrote a job to output a sorted dataframe with only one partition to one single csv file.  And I discovered several outcomes when using repartition differently.

At first, I used `orderBy` to sort the data and then used `repartition` to output a CSV file, but the output was sorted in chunks instead of in an overall manner.

Then, I tried to discard `repartition` function, but the output was only a part of the records.  I realized without using `repartition` spark will output 200 CSV files instead of 1, even though I am working on a one partition dataframe.

Thus, what I did next were placing `repartition(1)`, `repartition(1, "column of partition")`, `repartition(20)` function before `orderBy`.  Yet output remained the same with 200 CSV files.

So I used the `coalesce(1)` function before `orderBy`, and the problem was fixed.

I do not understand why working on a single partitioned dataframe has to use `repartition` and `coalesce`, and how the aforesaid processes affect the output.  Grateful if someone can elaborate a little.

Answer (score 1):

Spark has relevant parameters here:
`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and `spark.default.parallelism`.
When you perform operations like sort in your case, it triggers something called a shuffle operation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations

That will split your dataframe to `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` partitions.

I also struggled with the same problem as you do and did not find any elegant solution.

Comment: I understand that `orderBy` will perform data shuffling even I use `repartition(1)`, but then how is `coalesce(1)` different from `repartition(1)` in this case.  I output the count of partitions before and after `orderBy`, and in the case of `coalesce(1)` both counts were 1, however in the case of `repartition(1)` count after `orderBy` was 200.  Is it because `coalesce(1)` forces dataframe to preform operations in one partition no matter what? Since `coalesce(5)` did output 200 partitions after `orderBy` as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Spark generally doesn’t have a great concept of ordered data, because all your data is split accross multiple partitions. And every time you call an operation that requires a shuffle your ordering will be changed.
- For this reason, you’re better off only sorting your data in spark for the operations that really need it.
- Forcing your data into a single file will break when the dataset gets larger
- As Miroslav points out your data gets shuffled between partitions every time you trigger what’s called a shuffle stage (this is things like grouping or join or window operations)
  You can set the number of shuffle partitions in the spark Config - the default is 200
- Calling repartition before a group by operation is kind of pointless because spark needs to reparation your data again to execute the groupby
- Coalesce operations sometimes get pushed into the shuffle stage by spark. So maybe that’s why it worked. Either that or because you called it after the groupby operation
- A good way to understand what’s going on with your query is to start using the spark UI - it’s normally available at http://localhost:4040
  More info here https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/web-ui.html

Comment: I understand how `orderBy` triggers shuffling.  I just do not understand why only `coalesce(1)` avoided the shuffling.  Thanks.

Comment: Spark query planner will often combine the coalesce into the shuffle stage so that you get a coalesce rather than a shuffle. Check your query plan in the spark UI and you will be able to see what's happening.
Repartition is a very different operation to coalesce. Repartition always causes a full shuffle of  your data, and unless you repartition it in the exact way that spark needs it partitioned for your GroupBy operation, then spark will just shuffle/repartition it again

Comment: Seems like spark does not execute exchange when `coalesce(1)` is used, still I am not certain how.

Comment: Coalesce doesn't trigger an exchange. It's a different method to repartition and much more efficient https://blog.rockthejvm.com/repartition-coalesce/

Comment: But `coalesce(n != 1)` will trigger an exchange later in the process